# visit to Rome with Croatian Visa

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, croatia, rome

Iam an Indian citizen and  have a muti entry Croatian Visa. Can I visit Italy on my way to croatia  with that visa?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Croatia is still not a full member of Schengen area so Croatian visa does not allow you to visit any of the Schengen states.

*But it would work the other way round: a multi-entry Schengen visa allows you to visit Croatia.*